# Python ttk.Style: How to find all possible options to configure?

Tags: python, layout, styles, element, ttk

I'm using python2.7 on Linux. I started experimenting with ttk styles.
I wondered **where to find the complete Layout of a widget.** For example a Treeview.

When I run:

```
import ttk
from pprint import pprint
s = ttk.Style()
ttk.Treeview().pack()

layout = s.layout('Treeview')
pprint(layout)
```

I get this output:

```
[('Treeview.field',
  {'border': '1',
   'children': [('Treeview.padding',
                 {'children': [('Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                  'sticky': 'nswe'})],
   'sticky': 'nswe'})]
```

When I run:

```
s.configure('Treeview.Heading', background='red')
```

I get the desired red heading:

[image: Treeview with red heading]

My question is:

**How do I get the whole layout of the widgets?**

As I have found out about the existence of `Treeview.Heading` on the internet. **Why does it not appear in the output of** `s.layout`**?**

Comment: you mean how to get all the possible options to configure ?

Comment: yes. I assumed that would be done with the `.layout`-Method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved it:

```py
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from pprint import pprint                                                      

s = ttk.Style()                                                                
data = {}                                                                      
for e in s.element_names():                                                    
    data[e] = s.element_options(e)      

pprint(data)
```